# system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public static SqlDataReader reader(string query)
{
    SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlDataReader();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring());

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);


    sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    return sdr;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question? Why would you want to create an empty DataReader object?

Answer (score 1):

From [msdn's SqlDataReader documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To create a SqlDataReader, you must call the ExecuteReader method of the SqlCommand object, instead of directly using a constructor.

Your problem is trying to call the constructor with: `new SqlDataReader();`

How about this piece of code:

```
public static SqlDataReader reader(string query)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring());

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: thanks Arnon Zilca to notify my mistake...i was doing little mistake...correct code is                                                                    public static SqlDataReader reader(string query)
{
    SqlConnection con = null;

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
}

Comment: @RasheedQureshi glad i could help. please mark my answer accepted if it helped you (green v shaped tick).

Answer (score 0):

Correct code is:

```
public static SqlDataReader reader(string query)
{
    SqlConnection con = null;

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    return cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```